# JMeter - Using response data as variable

Tags: jmeter

The response I get back from a post is just a plain text guid seen here I'd like to pull this guid and use it in a variable for my following Get statement:
[post response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYRuO.png)

And I've tried a bunch of configurations in my regular expression extractor.
But it just ends up pulling Null when what I want is that guid.
[Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJYQJ.png)

I'm new to jmeter - so thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the whole response use the following [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration:

- Reference Name: `response`
- Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
- Template: `$1$`

[image: Regular Expression Configuration]

As per [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide:

> () = grouping
>
> (?s) = single line modifier
>
> ^ = line start
>
> . = wild-card character
>
> * = repetition

So it will return **the whole** response.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed - you're amazing. Thanks!